# How to handle error Positional argument after varargs in RF?

Tags: robotframework

I’m trying to create a user keyword “Create List Of List” to create list of list which has two lists as arguments.
When I run this, it shows error as  “***Creating user keyword 'Create List Of List' failed: Positional argument after varargs***.”

```
***  Test Cases ***
Sample test Case
    [Tags]    Test
    @{List1}=    Create List    a  b  c  d
    @{List2}=    Create List    1  2  3  4
    @{ListOfList}=    Create List Of List    @{List1}  @{List2}

*** Keywords ***
Create List Of List
     [Arguments]    @{List1}  @{List2}
     Log     Hello world
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

RF Version used: 2.8.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When passing a two lists to another keyword, you want to pass the *list*, not the individual elements of the list. To reference a list as an object, use `$` rather than `@`:

```
***  Test Cases ***
Sample test Case
    ...
    @{ListOfList}=    Create List Of List    ${List1}  ${List2}

*** Keywords ***
Create List Of List
     [Arguments]    ${List1}  ${List2}
     ...
```